# Google Protocol Buffer 3.0 - Serialized Length Is 0 After set_field(...)

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am using Google Protobuf 3.0.0. and ZeroMQ to achieve a connection between a server and some clients. So, my proto file looks something like this:

```
// message Request{} omitted
message Response{
 enum MessageType{
   Type1 = 0;
   Type2 = 1;
   Type3 = 2;
 }
 enum ConfirmationCode{
   OK = 0;
   Error1 = 1;
   Error2 = 2;
 }
 MessageType Type = 1;
 repeated someField1 field1 = 2;
 // ... some code omitted
 ConfirmationCode Confirm = 3;
}
```

As you can see, in ProtoBuf 3 there are no longer `required` or `optional` fields and I do not use any defaults. 
Now, I ran into some troubles when serializing some Protobuf messages and trying to send them over ZMQ. The serialization done by `google::protobuf::message_lite::SerializeToString(...)` does not fail but still, this method and `google::protobuf::message_lite::SerializeAsString()` produce empty strings, so I thought that maybe not a single field was set in my response before serializing and I introduced a method similar to the following

```
void InitResponse(Response& resp)
{
  resp.set_confirm(Response_ConfirmationCode_OK);
  resp.set_type(Response_MessageType_Type1);
}
```

to be sure that at least some fields were present. Still, before and after calling this method, my serialized response has a length of 0. I also tried using `google::protobuf::Message::DebugString()` but I think this method does not print every field present, since I always end up printing empty strings.

Why do my serialized messages end up empty if the serialization does not fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#default

> For enums, the default value is the first defined enum value, which must be 0.

You didn't alter the defaults at all in your `InitResponse`. Try setting anything else than you did :)

Comment: So, in other words: I cannot use GPB and ZMQ together if I do not set any values deviating from the defaults since it will always serialize to an empty string which I cannot send over ZMQ (AFAIk)?

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems that ZMQ accepts 0-length messages.

Comment: I never used ZMQ so TIL something too :)